# Accessing a SQL database from remote PC

Tags: python, mysql, sql

When I started hosting my website, I received a phpMyAdmin thing where I could manage the databases for the website. How can I access those databases from my remote PC?

I tried connecting to one using Python but I keep getting the error `(10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)` and I need help because I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import mysql.connector
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='someuser',
        password='somepass',
        database='database'
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
```

Comment: You need to open port 3309 on the firewall, and enable remote users in the MySQL configuration.

Comment: You have to change `host='localhost'` to the address of the computer running the DB.

Comment: @Barmar Remote users is enabled, but opening the port 3309? Isn't it 3306? 
Also, how can I find the address of the computer running the database?

Comment: You need to know the ip address of your database server to make a connection. Is the unique way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using localhost if you are connecting to a remote database which is on another server machine. Instead use the database server IP address:

```
import mysql.connector
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='11.162.174.78',
        port='3306',
        user='user_id',
        password='user_password',
        database='name_of_database'
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
```

Having said this, in your question above you mentioned 'managed the databases for the  website', to which I would suggest that you use a proper database management tool such as MySQL Workbench or HeidiSQL.

Comment: You are right, but the code itself is wrong... ```host="ip:port"``` will NOT work, you have to specify the port and the ip in different parameters, like this: ```host="ip", port="port"```, else it won't connect to the proper server.